# Thunar Icons Missing

Tags: icons, thunar, i3-wm

I installed thunar yesterday but on starting up this morning, I found that all of the folder icons had vanished. I'm using i3wm (but the icons were visible in i3 as of yesterday). Any idea why they might have disappeared or how I could retrieve them?

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In fact what happened was that I had removed unity and dependent packages. The icons went with it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try installing `gnome-icon-theme-full`.

Comment: Are you sure that's right?  The OP is using Xubuntu and Xfce.

Comment: I don't see how to post this as a response to another answer. Just wanted to confirm that I use Fluxbox as my WM, and the solution of installing gnome-icon-theme-full works great. I made sure that it did not install excessive dependencies before I hit 'Y'.

Comment: I had this issue with xubuntu and this fixed it

Comment: Why not `xubuntu-icon-theme`?

Comment: @Seth this answer seems to work, after I installed that package (no other dependencies/recommended/suggested were installed) almost all the icons were there, including those inside the applications menu

Answer (score 20):

I'm on Xubuntu 12.04 and using awesome WM. I can confirm that installing `gnome-icon-theme-full` partly solve the problem. I can also confirm it just install one single package without any excessive dependencies. But it has some side effects. It replaces some Xubuntu customised icons and makes them look weird. So I deleted it. After doing some search, I find another solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=67087) works better. Just install `lxappearance` and choose a icon theme. You can also change your gtk theme using it. It's weird that `xfce4-settings-manager` doesn't work under awesome.

Comment: easiest method so far.

Answer (score 8):

I run i3 on Xubuntu 18.04, this worked for me:

1. Create/modify the file `.gtkrc-2.0` in your home directory
2. Add/edit the line `gtk-icon-theme-name="gnome"`, change `gnome` to your desired icon theme.

This can be done by executing `echo "gtk-icon-theme-name=\"gnome\"" >> ~/.gtkrc-2.0` in your terminal.

Credit: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/no-icons-in-thunar-when-running-out-of-xfce-4175469261/#post4988339

Comment: And instead of "gnome" you can use any of the folder names from here: /usr/share/icons/ .

Answer (score 6):

Try setting some icon theme with, for example, `xfce4-settings-manager` and running `xfce4-settings-helper` before starting Thunar. It helps with awesome wm.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on XUbuntu 18.04 and I fixed it by opening the "Appearance" settings and going to the "Icons" tab. I selected "elementary Xfce" and the icons displayed correctly.

Note: I left "Adwaita" selected in the "Style" tab, but in the "Icons" tab the icon for "Adwaita" has a "broken icon/red ex" in it, I think this is an indication that some icon files are missing from that theme (I didn't track down why).