# How do I get icons for Thunar in 18.04?

Tags: icons, 18.04, thunar

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 (keeping my home folder) Thunar looks like this in an i3 session:

[image]

Apparently some icons are missing, but what do I have to install?

Note that the accepted answer [of this older question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173800/thunar-icons-missing) is obsolete since package `gnome-icon-theme-full` does not exist anymore. `xfce4-settings-helper` doesn't seem to exist anymore, either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The approach from [hrzhu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/272119/69674) still works:

- Install `lxappearance`.
- Run it and pick a working icon theme.
  Note how the default, Adwaita, seems to be broken.
- Restart Thunar.

[image]

Comment: same problem happened to me with icewm over ubuntu 18.04, `lxappearance` helped

Comment: this even sets correct icons for nautilus, which gnome-tweak-tool was unable to (in i3)

Answer (score 1):

I provided the same answer earlier for a similar question, with i3 on Xubuntu 18.04 this worked for me:

1. Create/modify the file `.gtkrc-2.0` in your home directory
2. Add/edit the line `gtk-icon-theme-name="gnome"`, change `gnome` to your desired icon theme.

This can be done by executing `echo "gtk-icon-theme-name=\"gnome\"" >> ~/.gtkrc-2.0` in your terminal.

Credit: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/no-icons-in-thunar-when-running-out-of-xfce-4175469261/#post4988339

Answer (score 0):

I came to this topic because I didn't like the new green icon for the download folder. So I did a research to fix it, I mean, to have the blue download icon back in my system.

Luckly I had a notebook with this blue icon and I found the exact path and file to change it. This icon is loaded from /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/places/16

Later I got excited and changed the Pictures icon too. See the result:

[image]

**How to do it**

1- Download the icon from here using mouse right button on the icon, option Save Image -> [image: This is the blue icon] [image: my pictures sugestion]

2- Open a terminal, and copy it to the right folder, supposing you saved the icon in ~/Downloads:

```
sudo cp  ~/Downloads/iQWdf.png /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/places/16/folder-downloads.png
sudo cp  ~/Downloads/QyNBX.png /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/places/16/folder-pictures.png
```